Get cumulative sums in a list without using a for loop
I want a list of the kind list = {a,a+b,a+b+c} for list plotting. The quantities of the list come from a function. Let us say this is
f[x_] = x^2

What I am doing is I start out with a list with a single entry, the first entry
dataset = {f[1]}

Then I write the following for loop
For[l = 2, l <= 50, l = l + 2, 
 AppendTo[dataset, dataset[[-1]] + f[l]]]

Obviously, this is very slow and further my function f[l] is actually a numerical sum of a very complicated expression. Is there any way to do this faster by using functional methods?

f[x_] := x^2

Accumulate[f /@ {1}~Join~Range[2, 50, 2]]

or
FoldList[#1 + f[#2] &, f[1], Range[2, 50, 2]]



{1, 5, 21, 57, 121, 221, 365, 561, 817, 1141, 1541, 2025, 2601, 3277,
\ 4061, 4961, 5985, 7141, 8437, 9881, 11481, 13245, 15181, 17297, 
19601, 22101}


Thanks @Syed . Is there a way to parallelize it?

It depends on the size of the input. If the input is a large list, then you may see some gain. Try Parallelize for instance. I would say this requires more information, a typical calculation, size of the list and your adopted solution. My suggestion would be to start a fresh question.

Cumulate[f_, r_] := Module[{n = 1}, Prepend[1] @ Map[n += f[#] &] @ r]

f[x_] := x^2


Cumulate[f, Range[2, 50, 2]]


{1, 5, 21, 57, 121, 221, 365, 561, 817, 1141, 1541, 2025, 2601, 3277, 
4061, 4961, 5985, 7141, 8437, 9881, 11481, 13245, 15181, 17297, 
19601, 22101}

Without pre-defined f
Cumulate[#^2 &, Range[2, 50, 2]]


same result

Compare with Accumulate
Rest @ Cumulate[# &, Range[5]] - 1 == Accumulate @ Range[5]


True


Thanks @eldo. Is there a way to parallelize it?

If f is "a very complicated expression" you could try to Compile it.
